# Sessions by hits.page.pagePath in GA bigquery tables

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am new to bigquery, so sorry if this is a noob question! I am interested in breaking out sessions by page path or title. I understand one session can contain multiple paths/titles so the sum would be greater than total sessions. Essentially, I want to create a 'session id' and do a count distinct of sessionids where path like a or b.

It might actually be helpful to start at the very beginning and manually calculate total sessions. I tried to concatenate visit id and full visitor id to create a unique visit id, but apparently that is quite different from sessions. Can someone help enlighten me? Thanks!

I am working with our GA site data. Schema is the [standard in GA](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) exports.

**DATA SAMPLE**

Let's use an example out of the sample [BigQuery (London Helmet) data](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416091?hl=en):

There are 63 sessions in this day:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]
```

How many of those sessions are where hits.page.pagePath like /vests% or /helmets%? How many were vests only vs helmets only? Thanks!

Comment: Mind posting the queries you already have, or the schema of the tables you're using? I personally like to know what table I'm writing a query for :). Provide a sample dataset, and the expected output you'd like to have for that dataset :)

Comment: I believe he means the standard schema generated by Google Analytics export to BigQuery

Comment: Thanks for your reply Patrice! I am working with our GA site data. Schema is the standard in GA exports: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Let's use an example out of the sample bigquery (London Helmet) data: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416091?hl=en

There are 63 sessions in this day:
    SELECT count(*) FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]

How many of those sessions are where hits.page.pagePath like /vests% or /helmets%? Thanks!

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky indeed. After posting my comment I looked up BQ and analytics and figured that this was a standard schema :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how to calculate whether there were only helmets, or only vests or both helmets and vests or neither:

```
SELECT 
  visitID,
  has_helmets AND has_vests AS both_helmets_and_vests,
  has_helmets AND NOT has_vests AS helmets_only,
  NOT has_helmets AND has_vests AS vests_only,
  NOT has_helmets AND NOT has_vests AS neither_helmets_nor_vests
FROM (
  SELECT
    visitId,
    SOME(hits.page.pagePath like '/helmets%') WITHIN RECORD AS has_helmets,
    SOME(hits.page.pagePath like '/vests%') WITHIN RECORD AS has_vests,
  FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] 
)
```

Comment: Hi Mosha, thanks for your reply! This is very enlightening... although I think there is the same initial issue as @Patrice where it is only looking at the first hit in the session. Is there a way to scour the entire session to group into helmets/vests/both/neither? Patrice also mentioned flattening, but ultimately I am still looking for session counts, not hits. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it looks only at first hit - it does look at all hits. hits is a REPEATED field, and WITHIN RECORD makes sure to iterate over all of them. FLATTEN is problematic, because it will erase boundaries between hits within a visit. I am not too familiar with GA schema though, is there something else to represent sessions (I assumed that visitID is session id).

Comment: Got it. This is a great place to start digging. Thanks!

Comment: Mosha, sorry this is a tangential question -- can you explain what the SOME() function is doing? I am having trouble finding any reference materials about it... I assume it is an aggregator function? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, SOME is aggregation function, and, together with EVERY it is function defined in SQL Standard. SOME does logical OR aggregation, while EVERY does logical AND.

Answer (score 2):

**Way 1, easier but you need to repeat on each field**

Obviously you can do something like this :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] WHERE hits.page.pagePath like '/helmets%'
```

And then have multiple queries for your own substrings (one with '/vests%', one with 'helmets%', etc).

**Way 2, works fine, but not with repeated fields**

If you want ONE query that'll just group by on the first part of the string, you can do something like that :

```
Select a, Count(*) FROM (SELECT FIRST(SPLIT(hits.page.pagePath, '/')) as a  FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ) group by a
```

When I do this, it returns me the following the 63 sessions, with a total count of 63 :).

**Way 3, using a FLATTEN on the table to get each hit individually**

Since the "hits" field is repeatable, you would need a FLATTEN in your query :

```
Select a, Count(*) FROM (SELECT FIRST(SPLIT(hits.page.pagePath, '/')) as a  FROM FLATTEN ([google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] , hits)) group by a
```

The reason why you need to FLATTEN here is that the "hits" field is repeatable. If you don't flatten, it won't look into ALL the "hits" in your response. Adding "FLATTEN" will make you work off a sub-table where each hit is in its own row, so you can query on all of them.

If you want it by sessions instead of hits, (it'll be both), do something like :

```
Select b, a Count(*) FROM (SELECT FIRST(SPLIT(hits.page.pagePath, '/')) as a, visitID as b, FROM FLATTEN ([google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] , hits)) group by b, a
```

Comment: Thanks Patrice! I notice when running just SELECT FIRST(SPLIT(hits.page.pagePath, '/')), hits.page.pagePath
  FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] there are 63 rows, which seems a little too clean. Can you explain this a little more because here is an example of a session where a visitor is looking at both helmet and vest during the same session: select hits.hitNumber, hits.page.pagePath FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] where visitid=1378805776 and fullvisitorid='380066991751227408'

Thanks!

Comment: @amysong Yes! It's actually simple, I just forgot about the flatten part. Since hits is a repeated field, my query was just looking at the first hit on each row. I added another one, with "flatten" on the table, and it returns more data. Running it with a flatten on your visitor ID, it gives me 3 helmets, 2 null, and 3 vests, which I can corroborate looking at the repeated field

Comment: Hi Patrice, that is very helpful, thank you. Flattening seems to bring it down to hit level granularity -- so count of rows gives me helmet or vest hit totals. I would still like sessions instead of hits. So in this data set, there are 362 total hits from 63 sessions... and 97 helmet hits, but how many helmet sessions? Hope this makes sense... thank you!

Comment: Yes indeed. You just need to add the visitID (or visitorID, I guess the session is visitID), and do a group by on it as well as the actual path. Look at the edit on my answer

Comment: Thanks for all your help understanding this better! Playing around with my data now...

Comment: @amysong the more I look at it the more I think the actual answer you want is the other one. Mine gives different counts and shows other things BQ can do, but I do think I misunderstood your use case :p.  That and I tried to make it generic (in case you wanted a more generic solution than simply 2 words you would need to type out)